# How to consume byte streams over a network without taking all the CPU time in Python

Tags: python, network-programming, bytesio

I have a Python server script which listens to a socket for stream of bytes

```py
import socket
server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8000))
server_socket.listen(0)

connection = server_socket.accept()[0].makefile('rb')
try:
    while True:
        byte_len = struct.unpack('<L', connection.read(struct.calcsize('<L')))[0]
        if not byte_len:
            break
        image_stream = io.BytesIO()
        image_stream.write(connection.read(byte_len))
        image_stream.seek(0)
        masked_frames = np.frombuffer(image_stream.getbuffer(), np.uint8)
```

I'm just omitting the rest of the code which is processing of a continues flow of images (in bytes)

This works fine BUT my question is regarding a better way (more optimized) way of consuming a stream of continues bytes over the network.

Considering my script as a realtime processing I did a quick research:

- Infinite loop might not be a good solution as its constantly takes 100% cpu time.
- I can play with niceness of the process but I don't think that should be dealt with in this case
- I can use `sleep` but if I use it, wouldn't I miss some data coming in or create a bottleneck?
- I heard of events, but, can it be used in this case? If yes how?

Could you please help me understand what is a better (more optimized) way of consuming a stream of continues bytes over a network connection without taking 100% CPU?

**Update**

Based on the comments I did an experiment.

- Moved the logic for processing image to another class `ImageProcessor`. Main loop is now just reading fixed number of bytes (1446336) & constructs numpy array. Then it adds the array to a `deque` in imageProcessor.

```py
   masked_frames.shape = (372, 1296, 3)
   end = timer()
   image_processor.add_to_queue(masked_frames)
   logger.info(f'Elapsed time to read {image_len} bytes and construct array: {(end - start)}')
```

This takes ≃ 332ms.

- In ImageProcessor class I'm creating a thread

```py
   def __init__(self):
        self.image_handler = ImagePersistenceHandler()
        self.queue = ImageQueue()
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.consume_images)
        t1.setName('Image Processor')
        t1.setDaemon(True)
        t1.start()
        logger.info('Image processor thread started successfully')
```

and the consume_images method is:

```py
    def consume_images(self):
        while True:
            if not self.queue.is_empty():
                start = timer()
                image = self.queue.dequeue()
```

Note that for brevity the rest is omitted.  Processing of an image takes ≃ 73ms. CPU usage is still 100% but the fan is running in a lower rpm (saying just based on sound of it).

Comment: It won't use 100% CPU. It will block when it's waiting for data from the network.

Comment: as soon as it receives data the cpu jumps to 100 and it stays there as stream of bytes are coming in.

Comment: The client must be sending data *very* rapidly. But if you slow down the reader, you'll create a backlog. You won't miss anything because TCP buffers all the data.

Comment: Don't worry about 100% CPU. Modern computers have multiple cores, you're only using 100% of one of them.

Comment: yes, the client is a PiCamera sending data very fast over the network using [capture_continuous](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/api_camera.html#picamera.camera.PiCamera.capture_continuous)

Comment: Maybe create `image_stream` once before the loop, rather than every time.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229369/discussion-between-vahid-and-barmar).

Comment: 'As soon as it receives data': in other words it did block until you received data, as @Barmar said, and from there on it is all image processing. Not reading from the network. You're looking at the wrong thing.

Comment: @user207421 But the issue is that as soon as he finshes image processing there's new data already waiting to be read, so it never blocks.

Comment: As I told him in chat, he needs to take the image processing out of the loop, because he can't keep up while doing that in real time.

Comment: @Barnar Of course, but that doesn't mean that he's using 100% CPU doing the reading. He is using it doing the image processing.

Comment: @Barmar, moving processing to another thread helped (check update) but still 100% CPU usage